# pegar valores de listview apos clique no MenuFlyoutItem

Tags: windows, context-menu

como pegar os valores de um listview feito em windowsphone 8.1 depois do clique em um MenuFlyoutItem. Exemplo tenho uma listview com id, nome e telefone apos segurar a lista para aparecer MenuFlyoutItem quero clicar em uma opção do menu e saber os valores do id, nome e telefone dessa linha selecionada.